# Failed to establish connection SQLSTATE: HY000[DataStax][Hardy] (22) Error from ThriftHiveClient: connect() failed: errno = 10061

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am using Datastax enterprise edition and in cluster one is Hadoop/Hive .I am trying to connect to hive with datastax hive odbc connector.I am getting error like :

```
Connector Version: V1.0.0.1007

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
Failed to establish connection
SQLSTATE: HY000[DataStax][Hardy] (22) Error from ThriftHiveClient: connect() failed: errno = 10061

TESTS COMPLETED WITH ERROR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 10061 means [connection refused](http://kbs.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/51/~/%5Bodbc-driver%5D-tcp%2Fip-%2810061%29-connection-refused)
Seems like you have not started the hive service on your Analytics node therefore nothing is listening on TCP 10000
Please login into one of your DSE Analytics node and execute:
dse hive --service hiveserver

Then try again your test from your Windows system

Source: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivStrtSvr.html